# Finding the length of the curve defined by $x(t)=t^2-2t$ and $y(t)=t^3-4t$ for $0\leq t\leq2$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

So I was given the following prompt:

> What is the length of the curve defined by the parametric equations $x(t)=t^2-2t$ and $y(t)=t^3-4t$ for $0\leq t\leq2$?

I understand the setup for the length formula, but I'm a bit confused about what the integral would look like for this equation.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$L=\int_{0}^{2} \sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2+(\frac{dy}{dt})^2} ~ dt$$
Here $dx/dt=2(1-t), dy/dt=3t^2-4$. We get
$$L=\int_{0}^{2} \sqrt{9t^4-20t^2-8t+20} ~dt, $$
which is not doable by hand, It can be done numerically and Mathematica gives $6.5105$.

Answer (score 1):

what you have is essentially:
$$L=\int dL$$
where we know that:
$$dL=\sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}=\sqrt{\frac{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}{dt^2}}dt=\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}dt$$
which is where the formula comes from, now work out the derivatives:
$$y=t^3-4t$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=3t^2-4\Rightarrow y'^2=(3t^2-4)^2$$
$$x=t^2-2t$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=2t-2=2(t-1)\Rightarrow x'^2=4(t-1)^2$$
now just combine the two:
$$(y')^2+(x')^2=(3t^2-4)^2+4(t-1)^2=9t^4-20t^2-8t+20$$
now remember we are square-rooting then integrating wrt $t$ so:
$$I=\int_0^2\sqrt{9t^4-20t^2-8t+20}\,dt$$